# Panel.Dispose closes context menu, why?

Tags: winforms, focus, contextmenu, dispose, toolstripcontrolhost

As per Cody's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804411/how-to-prevent-enter-press-from-closing-menu), I derived a class from ContextMenuStrip and handle the ProcessCmdKey. This successfully prevents the menu from closing when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> while a textbox embedded inside the menu has focus. So all is well except for one thing.

Upon the Enter press, I remove the Textbox from the menu, and disposing this control causes the menu to close. When I do this:

```
If (m_inputPanel IsNot Nothing) Then m_inputPanel.Hide()
If (m_inputPanel IsNot Nothing) Then m_inputPanel.Parent.Controls.Remove(m_inputPanel)
If (m_inputPanel IsNot Nothing) Then m_inputPanel.Dispose()
```

the menu is closed. When I comment out the third line, the menu remains open. (Incidentally, m_inputPanel.Parent is a custom control which is embedded inside the menu using a ToolStripControlHost)

Why on God's Green Earth does it matter that I dispose a control which is no longer part of the menu?

Comment: Check this answer for a better way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207767/net-multiple-toolstripbuttons-in-a-single-contextmenuitem/5207964#5207964

Comment: I just noticed this question, and feel somewhat compelled to reply since I'm the one that gave you the original solution. In this case, I agree with Hans. I tried to suggest in the comments to your previous question that I didn't think using a `ContextMenuStrip` was the best general approach to your problem, but since the immediate solution was so simple, I tried to provide a helpful answer. I'm sorry if you've wasted a bunch of time getting the CMS to work. I don't know a workaround here; I don't use the CMS much myself for multiple reasons, including the fragile behavior Hans discusses.

Comment: @Cody, not at all. I'm most grateful for your answer. The Disposing problem might yet be overcome, and even if it isn't, I can always figure out a way to add these controls to some sort of list to be disposed after the menu is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You are removing focus from the context menu when you do this, since it was the textbox that had focus when you removed it now there is nothing in the `ContextMenuStrip` that has focus any more.

Comment: So not disposing the textbox but removing it from the menu as a control *doesn't* remove focus? Hmm, odd. Though it explains what's happening. I'll try and set focus back to the menu prior to disposing, see if that helps.

Comment: @DavidRutten that is an interesting question, I would image that it is some odd caveat of the controls.

Comment: It is an excellent theory.  Unfortunately that should also close the CMS when the panel is hidden and not disposed.